# Handling errors in async event handlers in JavaScript in the web browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, error-handling, es6-promise

This is just another hopeless try to handle errors in async event handlers.

***A note about this example:*** The example here works differently than it does if it is run directly in the browser. If ran directly in the browser none of the event listeners for errors is working ("error", "unhandledrejection").

It looks similar on Windows 10 in Chrome (Version 80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and Firefox (75.0 (64-bit)).

The only way I have found to handle this is to never make any typos. But that does not work either for me.

How is this supposed to work?

```js
window.addEventListener("error", evt => {
    console.warn("error event handler", evt);
    output("error handler: " + evt.message, "yellow");
});
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", evt => {
    console.warn("rejection event handler", evt);
    output("rejection handler: " + evt.message, "green");
});
function output(txt, color) {
    const div = document.createElement("p");
    div.textContent = txt;
    if (color) div.style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

const btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.innerHTML = "The button";
btn.addEventListener("click", async evt => {
    evt.stopPropagation();
        output("The button was clicked");
        noFunction(); // FIXME: 
})
document.body.appendChild(btn);

const btn2 = document.createElement("button");
btn2.innerHTML = "With try/catch";
btn2.addEventListener("click", async evt => {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    try {
        output("Button 2 was clicked");
        noFunction2(); // FIXME: 
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn("catch", err)
        throw Error(err);
    }
})
document.body.appendChild(btn2);

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        return reject('oh noes');
    }, 100);
});

justAnError();
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
<script defer src="error-test.js"></script>
```

---

EDIT - adding output from Chrome and JS Bin
([Link to JS Bin example](https://jsbin.com/huxitet/edit?html,js,console,output))

**Loading page**

Chrome/Firefox:

> error handler: Script error.

JS Bin:

> error handler: Uncaught ReferenceError: justAnError is not defined
>
> rejection handler: undefined

**Clicking left button**

Chrome/Firefox:

> The button was clicked

JS Bin:

> The button was clicked
>
> rejection handler: undefined

Comment: *"If ran directly in the browser none of the event listeners for errors is working"* [They do for me](https://output.jsbin.com/cehucatiga) (Chrome, Firefox), locally and in that JSBin. Please post a complete HTML page replicating the problem, **exactly** as you're authoring it locally.

Comment: Note: I strongly recommend **not** using `async` functions directly as event handlers. The event system doesn't do anything with the promise they return, which is why errors in them end up being unhandled rejections. If you want to centralize error handling for them, one option would be to have a wrapper function: `addEventListener("event", handler(async evt => { /*...*/ })`. The `handler` function would call the `async` function and handle any rejections using your centralized means of doing so.

Comment: "*The only way I have found to handle this is to never make any typos*" - uh, these event handlers cannot *handle* typos in your code either. At best, they can notify you about them. In development, the console can do that as well, in production, the best solution is not to roll out wrong code :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The code I have posted here is exactly the same as I use when I test locally. (It looks incomplete, but this structure is accordning to some of Google's advices.)

Comment: @Bergi There is a lot of AI solutions for this when you are just writing text (Grammarly, etc). So why not for code? It is much more structured. Sometimes. :-|

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I see. So `handler` is a function taking a promise as an argument?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Tried JSBIN. It does not work exactly as in the browser there either. https://jsbin.com/huxitet/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Leo - Please be more specific about what you mean by "does not work." I get the same results from the snippet, JSBin, and local. *"So `handler` is a function taking a promise as an argument?"* No, it takes an `async` function as an argument, and returns a function to use as the event handler; that function handles rejections: ```function handler(fn) { return function(evt) { fn(evt).catch(e => { /*...handle rejection in `e`... */}); }; }```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, yes. I was just trying to implement the suggestion and realized what you mean. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have to go now, but I will add the output I get to the question when I get back tonight.

Comment: @Leo There are linters and typecheckers for code, they will catch most simple spelling mistakes just as well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just added the screen output I see. Note that the rejection handler is run in JS Bin, but not in Chrome/Firefox. (I also made a mistake in my code about the structure of the Error object. That always confuses me.)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I do not use the linter in the editor. I am using VScode now (on a rather slow laptop) and it is unfortunately quite buggy, I see a lot of race conflicts. I turned off the linter because of this. (I am using the VIM extension. Previously I used Emacs with VIP and after fixing bugs there it worked very well. But I do not have time to use Emacs now.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Your solution works nicely. Could you please make it a solution here so other people can find it? I remember now I stumbled over this before, but did not quite understand what is going on. Why does it work this way?

Comment: @Leo - Sure, if you like. Which solution? [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61080783/handling-errors-in-async-event-handlers-in-javascript-in-the-web-browser?noredirect=1#comment108065200_61080783)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. Yes, the "handler" function. If you explain why this is necessary it would be much more easy to remember. Why can't the compiler detect a case like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give yourself utility functions for error reporting and wrapping event handlers, like this:

```
function handleError(err) {
    if (!(err instanceof Error)) {
        err = Error(err);
    }
    output("error handler: " + err.message, "yellow");
}

function wrapHandler(fn) {
    return function(evt) {
        new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve(fn(evt));
        }).catch(e => {
            handleError(e);
        });
    };
}
```

That supports both `async` and non-`async` event handlers. If there's a synchronous error calling `fn`, it's caught by the promise constructor and turned into a rejection of the promise being created. If there isn't, the promise is resolved to the return value of the `fn`, meaning that if `fn` returns a promise that rejects, the promise created by `new Promise` is rejected. So either way, errors go to the error handler.

I haven't tried to distinguish between errors and rejections, as they're fundamentally the same thing, but you could if you want:

```
function handleError(err, isRejection) {
    if (!(err instanceof Error)) {
        err = Error(err);
    }
    output("error handler: " + err.message, isRejection ? "green" : "yellow");
}

function wrapHandler(fn) {
    return function(evt) {
        try {
            const result = fn(event);
            Promise.resolve(result).catch(e => handleError(e, true));
        } catch (e) {
            handleError(e, false);
        }
    };
}
```

Either way, you'd set up your global handlers to use it and prevent the default:

```
window.addEventListener("error", errorEvent => {
    handleError(errorEvent.error, false); // Remove the `, false` if you're not trying to make a distinction
    errorEvent.preventDefault();
});

window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", errorEvent => {
    handleError(errorEvent.reason, true); // Remove the `, true` if you're not trying to make a distinction
    errorEvent.preventDefault();
});
```

You'd use `wrapHandler` when setting up your handlers, either directly:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", wrapHandler(async evt => {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    output("The button was clicked");
    noFunction(); // FIXME: 
}));
```

...or by having another utility function:

```
function addListener(elm, eventName, fn) {
    const handler = wrapHandler(fn);
    return elm.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
    return function() {
        elm.removeEventListener(handler);
    };
}
```

...then:

```
const removeBtnClick = addListener(btn, "click", async evt => {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    output("The button was clicked");
    noFunction(); // FIXME: 
});
// ...if you want to remove it later...
removeBtnClick();
```

Live Example — since your original distinguished between synchronous errors and rejections, I've used that variant here, but again, its' really a distinction without a difference and I wouldn't distinguish them in my own code:

```js
function handleError(err, isRejection) {
    if (!(err instanceof Error)) {
        err = Error(err);
    }
    output("error handler: " + err.message, isRejection ? "green" : "yellow");
}

window.addEventListener("error", errorEvent => {
    handleError(errorEvent.error, false);
    errorEvent.preventDefault();
});

window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", errorEvent => {
    handleError(errorEvent.reason, true);
    errorEvent.preventDefault();
});

function wrapHandler(fn) {
    return function(evt) {
        try {
            const result = fn(event);
            Promise.resolve(result).catch(e => handleError(e, true));
        } catch (e) {
            handleError(e, false);
        }
    };
}

function addListener(elm, eventName, fn) {
    const handler = wrapHandler(fn);
    return elm.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
    return function() {
        elm.removeEventListener(handler);
    };
}

function output(txt, color) {
    const div = document.createElement("p");
    div.textContent = txt;
    if (color) div.style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

const btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.innerHTML = "The button";
addListener(btn, "click", async evt => {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    output("The button was clicked");
    noFunction(); // FIXME: 
});
document.body.appendChild(btn);

const btn2 = document.createElement("button");
btn2.innerHTML = "With try/catch";
addListener(btn2, "click", async evt => {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    try {
        output("Button 2 was clicked");
        noFunction2(); // FIXME: 
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn("catch", err)
        throw Error(err);
    }
});
document.body.appendChild(btn2);

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        return reject('oh noes');
    }, 100);
});

justAnError();
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very nice.

Comment: Just a clarification: Your solution works for both async and non-async event handlers. But as I understand it it is not needed in the non-async case.

Comment: @Leo - Well, it provides nice centralized error handling even for non-`async` handlers. :-)